# Can I call a function from unknown source safely?

Tags: c

I want to receive some C code from the user and compile it Just-In-Time using tcc compiler. The compiler then gives me a pointer to a function in the compiled code. I want to call this function safely so that if this function causes a crash it just returns with an integer representing error, is this possible?
([This is an example of how I want to use tcc compiler library](https://github.com/LuaDist/tcc/blob/master/tests/libtcc_test.c))

Comment: It's not only crashes you have to worry about, what if the code does something to your system? In short, you can't rely on user-code and need to run such code in a *sandbox*.

Comment: ...An air-gapped _sandbox_.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The code is supposed to be just math operations, which the program will use to evaluate a color or a normal at some place, like a shader.

Comment: What does what the function “is supposed to be” have to do with what it actually is? Do you think criminals will obey your rules?

Comment: The question totally depends on the definitions of "crash" and "safe", neither of which are currently provided, so it seems too broad IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to call this function safely so that if this function causes a crash it just returns with an integer representing error, is this possible

That alone is potentially possible. Most things that cause a crash will cause a signal; which means that you can call `setjump()` before calling the unsafe code, then have signal handler/s that use `longjmp()` to restore a known state if the unsafe code crashes.

> Can I call a function from unknown source safely?

That is a lot more than just guarding against crashes - you might also have to guard against deliberately malicious code that does not crash.

However; this depends on what you consider "safe" and how your software would be used. Typically (for personal computers, not servers) there is nothing that the end user could do that they couldn't also do by compiling their code with their own compiler and running it themselves (and this includes loading and starting your software into a forked process with malware injected into the virtual address space, then tampering with everything your code does); so "safe" (or "less safe than the user can already do anyway") becomes hard to define in meaningful way.

The only valid concern that I can think of is when the user has less permissions/privileges than your software (where the user could abuse your software to gain permissions/privileges they didn't already have). In this case; you shouldn't be considering letting the user run arbitrary code (it's simply too hard to make it safe).